# Use fileupload Or Actionbutton to trigger a response in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have created the following app using R shiny

```
library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Hello World!"),sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(fileInput('file', 'Load Excel File', accept=c(".xlsx"), multiple = TRUE),
 sliderInput(inputId = "bins",label = "Number of bins:",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30),
 actionButton(inputId = "Go", label = "Goooo!")),
 mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "Table_Out") ) ))


server <- function(input, output) {values4<-reactiveValues(cpt4=0)
observeEvent(input$Go, values4$cpt4 <- input$bins)
bintable<-reactive({N=values4$cpt4
Sequ_Bin<-seq(0, N, 1)
Seq_DF<-data.frame("A"= Sequ_Bin)
return(Seq_DF) })  
 execelTable1<-reactive({
infile=input$file
data=readxl::read_excel(infile$datapath)
return(data)})  
 finalOutputtable<-reactive({
 bintable<-bintable()
execelTable1<-execelTable1()
if(is.null(execelTable1)==F){finalOutputtable=bintable 
 }else{ finalOutputtable=execelTable1}
return(finalOutputtable)})
 output$Table_Out <- renderDataTable({
 finalOutputtable<-finalOutputtable()
 return(finalOutputtable)}) }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The Number of Bins is changed by means of the slider. The same is stored as a reactivval values4$cpt4. This works when the Goooo! button is pressed.
I want the App to display a table as follows. When Excel is loaded, It displays the Excel data. When Excel is not loaded and The go button is pressed, it displays a table that changes based on  no of bins. However, I am unable to get the go button to work independent without first uploading the excel. and the Data from excel doesnt render when the go button is not pressed , which is what is expected.
I request someone to guide me here. Am unable to figure this out.

Comment: You are missing `()` in `finalOutputtable=bintable()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Hello World!"),sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(fileInput('file', 'Load Excel File', accept=c(".xlsx"), multiple = TRUE),
               sliderInput(inputId = "bins",label = "Number of bins:",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30),
               actionButton(inputId = "Go", label = "Goooo!")),
  mainPanel(DTOutput(outputId = "Table_Out") ) 
))


server <- function(input, output) {
  values4<-reactiveValues(cpt4=0)
  observeEvent(input$Go, {values4$cpt4 <- input$bins})
  bintable<-reactive({N=values4$cpt4
    Sequ_Bin<-seq(0, N, 1)
    Seq_DF<-data.frame("A"= Sequ_Bin)
    return(Seq_DF) })  
  
  execelTable1<-reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)){
      data <- bintable()
    }else {
      infile=input$file
      data=readxl::read_excel(infile$datapath)
    }
    return(data)
  })  
  
  # finalOutputtable<-reactive({
  #    bintable<-bintable()
  #    execelTable1<-execelTable1()
  #    if(is.null(execelTable1())==F){finalOutputtable=bintable 
  #    }else{ finalOutputtable=execelTable1}
  # return(finalOutputtable)})
  
  output$Table_Out <-  renderDT({
    finalOutputtable <- execelTable1() # finalOutputtable()
  return(finalOutputtable)}) 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```